# Javascript alert on page load based on the value of controller variable

Tags: javascript, controller, parameters

I am getting the value of booleanvariable  in controller as below. I want to display an alert on visual force page when boolean variable is true.I see the value of Booleanvariable is true in the url,but alert is not triggering.

```
public with sharing class TestBoolean {

boolean pbv;

public TestBoolean(){    

     try{     pbv = boolean.valueOf(system.CurrentPageReference().GetParameters().get('BooleanVariableName'));
  }catch(Exception e){ 
  pbv = false;
 }

}
```

If I just run alert without If condition and no parameter, its displaying alert.
Any help is appreciated.

Java script for alert on visual force page

```
window.onload = showAlert(!pbv);
function showAlert(!pbv) 
{
  if(!pbv) {
    alert('Hi I am the alert you have been waiting for');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is this for the JS (Global merge variables)

```
window.onload = showAlert();
function showAlert() 
{
  if('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.BooleanVariableName}' == 'true') {
    alert('Hi I am the alert you have been waiting for');
  }
}
```

Additionally (Not needed for above) if you want to use the PBV on the page you need to assign getters and setters

```
public Boolean PBV {get; set;}
```

then use merge fields on the page:

```
{!PBV}
```

Also, you should use the first example in my answer to your previous question. The try catch in not applicable in your case

Comment: @martin - thx for the edit

Comment: Awesome Eric. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SFDC - Since you are new I will point out that if your question gets answered please accept the answer so others looking for similar issues can find answers as well. Glad it worked for you. Cheers.